# How to get a substring of text?

Tags: ruby

I have text with length ~700. How do I get only ~30 of its first characters?

Comment: The OP works in Rails and asks for a solution in Rails, so [apneadiving](https://stackoverflow.com/users/350087/apneadiving), [Joó Adám](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123288/jo%c3%b3-%c3%81d%c3%a1m) and I think question should be (re)tagged with Rails.

Answer (score 262, accepted):

If you have your text in `your_text` variable, you can use:

```
your_text[0..29]
```

Comment: So basically 3 dots(...) means the end is exclusive and 2 dots(..) means the end is inclusive.

Answer (score 222):

Use [`String#slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-slice), also aliased as `[]`.

```
a = "hello there"
a[1]                   #=> "e"
a[1,3]                 #=> "ell"
a[1..3]                #=> "ell"
a[6..-1]               #=> "there"
a[6..]                 #=> "there" (requires Ruby 2.6+)
a[-3,2]                #=> "er"
a[-4..-2]              #=> "her"
a[12..-1]              #=> nil
a[-2..-4]              #=> ""
a[/[aeiou](.)\1/]      #=> "ell"
a[/[aeiou](.)\1/, 0]   #=> "ell"
a[/[aeiou](.)\1/, 1]   #=> "l"
a[/[aeiou](.)\1/, 2]   #=> nil
a["lo"]                #=> "lo"
a["bye"]               #=> nil
```

Comment: To be clear, `-1` is used to get to the end of the string, so **`a[1..-1] #=> "ello there"`**.

Comment: This may be obvious to some, but it is **not** okay to use a comma for negative positions: `a[-4,-2]`. The only valid notation is the two dots: `a[-4..-2]`. Learnt it the hard way.

Answer (score 24):

Since you tagged it Rails, you can use truncate:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate

Example:

```
 truncate(@text, :length => 17)
```

Excerpt is nice to know too, it lets you display an excerpt of a text Like so:

```
 excerpt('This is an example', 'an', :radius => 5)
 # => ...s is an exam...
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-excerpt

Comment: @JoóÁdám tag was changed by Andrew Marshall

Answer (score 15):

if you need it in **rails** you can use [first](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.6/classes/String.html#method-i-first) ([source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9e67954dcfdc92f1087a03c0b1c61251d993e270/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/access.rb#L75))

```
'1234567890'.first(5) # => "12345"
```

there is also [last](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.6/classes/String.html#method-i-last) ([source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9e67954dcfdc92f1087a03c0b1c61251d993e270/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/access.rb#L95))

```
'1234567890'.last(2) # => "90"
```

alternatively check [from/to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.6/classes/String.html#method-i-from) ([source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9e67954dcfdc92f1087a03c0b1c61251d993e270/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/access.rb#L44)):

```
"hello".from(1).to(-2) # => "ell"
```

Comment: yes, it is. but you also can copy source code form links that I posted

Answer (score 1):

If you want a string, then the other answers are fine, but if what you're looking for is the first few letters as characters you can access them as a list:

```
your_text.chars.take(30)
```