# Ruby Methods to Return Individual Letters

Tags: ruby

I wondering if there is a way to return the first letter of a word. like if you type in word("hey") it will return just the letter h. or if you wanted to you could return the letter e. individually by themselves. I was considering using the break method or scan but I can't seem to make them work.

Comment: `string[0]` and that is it.

Comment: you could use a range, like this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184697/how-to-get-a-substring-of-text

Comment: @oldergod You could use `"hey".chr` as seen below.

Comment: Ahh man why does everyone downvote my stupid questions I'm a newbie :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a naive implementation, but you could use `method_missing` to create a DSL that'd allow you to query a word for letters at different positions:

```
def self.method_missing(method, *args)
  number_dictionary = {
    first: 1,
    second: 2,
    third: 3,
    fourth: 4,
    fifth: 5,
    sixth: 6,
    seventh: 7,
    eighth: 8,
    ninth: 9,
    tenth: 10
  }

  if method.to_s =~ /(.+)_letter/ && number = number_dictionary[$1.to_sym]
    puts args[0][number - 1]
  else
    super
  end
end

first_letter('hey')  # => 'h'
second_letter('hey') # => 'e'
third_letter('hey')  # => 'y'
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

```
def first_letter(word)
  word[0]
end
```

Or, if using Ruby 1.8:

```
def first_letter(word)
  word.chars[0]
end
```

Use the syntax `str[index]` to get a specific letter of a word (0 is first letter, 1 second, and so on).

Comment: it just returns 104? what does that mean?

Comment: @Evan That is the ascii value in decimal for "h".

Comment: @Evan: Oh! You're on an *old* version of Ruby. Hold on.

Comment: @Evan: Try the second version.

Comment: A better pattern if one wants it to work on 1.8 .. 2.0 is `word[0..0]`

Comment: @dbenhur: Never thought of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

another method you can look at is `chr` which returns the first character of a string

```
>> 'hey'.chr # 'h'
```

you can also look at http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-slice to see how you can combine regexp and indexes to get a part of a string.

UPDATE: If you are on ruby 1.8, it's a bit hackish but

```
>> 'hey'[0] # 104
>> 'hey'[0..0] # 'h'
>> 'hey'.slice(0,1) # 'h'
```

Comment: The OP seems to be on ruby 1.8 and `chr` is not available back then :(

Comment: that's a bummer then. anyway, there's lots of ways to do what he wants in whatever version of ruby :)

Comment: @jvnill: Take a look at my answer.

Comment: I'm in 1.9.3 so im fine with chr. this really helped thanks jvnill

Comment: Yeah I was using a online generator at first. The Ruby on my computer is 1.9.3.

Answer (score 0):

Using your example - the word "hey":

```
h = "hey"

puts h[0]
```

This should return `h`.