# How to split a string in n substring?

Tags: ruby

I began with ruby and I have a problem.
I want to split a string in many substring.

For example, I have this string:

```
str = "a9547e"
```

And I want to split it in two substrings of three characters or three substrings of two characters. And I get something like that:

```
str = ["a9","54","7e"]
str = ["a94","47e"]
```

I tried different things, but nothing works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a substring of text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184697/how-to-get-a-substring-of-text)

Comment: You want to split a 7 character string into (2 substrings * 3 characters) or (3 substrings * 2 characters)?

Comment: Your question is about to be closed because it is not clear. You have not explained what is to be done if the length of the string is not evenly divisible by 2 or 3. Nor have you indicated whether the group size (2 or 3) is to be given or determined by the method. Lastly, you have not responded to @ndnenkov's comment, which is rude and unprofessional (your behaviour, not the comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I completely understand the intention but how about something like this

```
def string_splitter(str,group_length) 
  str.each_char.each_slice(group_length).map(&:join)
end 

str = "a9547e"
string_splitter(str,2)
#=> ["a9","54","7e"]
string_splitter(str,3)
#=> ["a94","47e"]
```

Caveat if the string is not evenly divisible this will offer an uneven ending group e.g.

```
str = "a9547eP"
string_splitter(str,2)
#=> ["a9","54","7e", "P"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this is what I want. And don't worry, I make sure that the string is divisible.

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed the group size is given and the method is to return `nil` if the length of the string is not evenly divisble by the group size.

```
def split_in_groups(str, group_size)
  n, rem = str.size.divmod(group_size)
  str.scan(/.{#{n}}/) if rem.zero? 
end
```

```
split_in_groups("a9547e", 2)
  #=> ["a95", "47e"] 
split_in_groups("a9547e", 3)
  #=> ["a9", "54", "7e"]
split_in_groups("a9547e", 1)
  #=> ["a9547e"] 
split_in_groups("a9547e", 5)
  #=> nil
```

If, for example,

```
str = "a9547e"
group_size = 2
```

then

```
n, rem = str.size.divmod(group_size)
  #=> [3, 0]
n #=> 3 (same as str.size/group_size)
rem
  #=> 0 (remainder) 
str.scan(/.{#{n}}/) if rem.zero?
  #=> str.scan(/.{3}/) if true
  #=> str.scan(/.../)  
  #=> ["a95", "47e"]
```

See [Integer#divmod](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html#method-i-divmod) (a very useful, but underutilised, method) and [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-scan).